# how can i verify if html input is >0 and is not a string

Tags: javascript, html

i have tried a lot of times but i didnt find a solution

```html
<html>

<head>

<title>Nouvelle page 1</title>
</head>

<body>
    
<form method="POST" action=""  name="F">
    
    <p><input type="text" name="T1" size="20"><input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="B1" onclick="verif()"><input type="reset" value="Retablir" name="B2"></p>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
        
    function verif()
    {
        x = document.F.T1.value;
        Number(x);
        while ((x<0 ) || (typeOf(x)=="NaN"))
        {
            alert('donner un entier positif');
        }
    
    }
    
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you could try `if (!(x>0)) { /* alert... */ }`

Comment: by the way, `typeof` alone cannot tell you if a value is `NaN`. `typeof NaN` is actually equal to `"number"`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: i used isNaN() and it worked .thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to assign Number(x) for a variable in the function:

```
function verif()
{
    x = document.F.T1.value;
    var number = Number(x);
    if ((number<0 ) || (typeOf(number)=="NaN"))
    {
        alert('donner un entier positif');
    }

}
```

And you can use HTML validate

```
<input type="number" min="0" name="T1" size="20">
```

Comment: thank you it works fine on >0 condition but not on the not only number one.i took your function and modified it and it worked thnx!  and did this: `if ((y<0 ) || (isNaN(y)))`